# Why does datetime.date not provide strptime?

Tags: python

The python module `datetime.datetime` provides `strftime` and `strptime`.

`datetime.date` provides only `strftime`.

Why is that?

Comment: In the `datetime.datetime` you are getting date **and time**. But in `datetime.date` you get **only the date part** of the datetime.

Comment: I can only speculate, but I suppose it's probably because they didn't see the need to implement a dumbed down copy of `strptime` when you can simply do `datetime.strptime(...).date()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) is a *class method* that *generates* `datetime` objects. Since a `datetime` is more general than a `date` object and the latter can be retrieved from the former via `.date()` and there is no need to reimplement this method (besides having a method called `date.strptime` would be quite confusing since it mixes terms "date" and "time" while it's actually just a date).

On the other hand [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) and [`date.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) are *instance methods* that transform a given object. In order to provide the same functionality for `date` objects this methods needs to reimplemented (also because mapping `date -> datetime` is ambiguous).

Note that in Python 3.7 there was the [`date.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat) *classmethod* added, as a convenience method for parsing specific date strings (inverse to [`date.isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat)).